# Python: Database permission

Tags: python, database, permissions

For an assignment, I am to create a database and an input page that will allow users put information into this database. My question is, what is the permission that this database should have? I have the database.py in the correct directory. Should it be permission 700? or 644? Thanks.

Comment: python has built in support for sqlite. http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: I'm very confused on what you are trying to do. What is the database? Is database.py a driver to connect and work with an existing database (such as MySQL or SQLite3)? Or is database.py a pseudo database where you are storing input into a struct or class from user input, so once the script finishes, the data is gone. Also, how is this going to be used? Someone logging onto your system as a restricted user vs someone just using the running script by sitting in your chair are things to consider when setting permissions.

Comment: which database are you trying to connect ? the permission of the file database.py should atleast have exe permission for the user.  755 will give exe permission for all.

Comment: @RyanG database.py is thru SQLite3. So the information will not be erased once the script finishes. It will be only accessible to restricted users who have the correct password. Sorry. I'm confused on how to do any of this.

Comment: @Rahul database.py is the database that my hw6.py is trying to connect to to store information into. So do I set database.py to 755?

Comment: Will the database.py script run as a daemon? (Run forever and wait for a signal from hw6.py) Or will hw6.py take some input and then run the database.py method/module with some given input parameters from the user. If this second case is true, then your database.py file should have the same permissions as your hw6.py, and the permissions will need to be set appropriately for the database.sqlite3 file, because this is where the writing actions will be taken place. Remember permisions are Owner:Group:Global, so depending on who is logged into the system set permissions for them. Try 666.